# Type or namespace 'Sqlite' could not be found in SQLite.cs

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that utilizes SQLite.  The app has many database functions, and includes a sqlite database file which, upon running the app, is copied to the local folder and accessed.  All of this worked with no problem until I first switched to release build, upon which it did not work.

I "fixed" this by deleting all NuGet references and .dll references and started over following the steps here:[A Workaround to Use SQLite in a Windows Phone 8 Application](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/workaround-use-sqlite-windows)

I am having a frustrating problem where, after switching from debug to release build, or vice versa, 'Sqlite' is once again no longer recognized.

I get the following errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'Sqlite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

These errors are coming from SQLite.cs, specifically these lines:

```
using Sqlite3 = Sqlite.Sqlite3;
using Sqlite3DatabaseHandle = Sqlite.Database;
using Sqlite3Statement = Sqlite.Statement;
```

How is this possible?  I saw some similar questions on here, but all of them simply said to delete and re-add the references and the problem inexplicably goes away.  This is not working for me.

Comment: Is that a compile-time error you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18204.how-to-use-sqlite-with-a-windows-phone-8-application.aspx) to configure your project. Also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19453315/2654404)

> Second you will need to go to the GITHUB website and  **[download the
>   code for SQLite-net-wp8](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8)**.   This is a c++ project you will need to
>   access a sqlite database.

Make you sure you set Conditional compilation symbols: USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE and release is x86 or ARM.

Tested on VS Profesional 2013, Release build (x86, ARM)

Answer (score 0):

Go thorough bellow link

[Windows Phone 7 Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)

Hope it will help you