# Error : while working with SQLite in windows phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

this is my first post. I get this error

> The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not
>   supported by the referenced SDK "SQLite.WP80, Version=3.8.10.2".
>   Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your
>   project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration
>   Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, ARM".

while working in windows phone app and using SQLite. If I set the architecture to ARM then it will disappear but I got another error of missing "community" from namespace in SQLite.cs file. Any one can help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask question on stackoverflow..  and are you working on Windows Phone 8 or Windows Phone 8.1 platform..?

Answer (score 1):

follow this:

Install Extension "SQLite for Windows Phone" from `Tools -> Extension and Updates Menu`. check screenshot 1

[image]

Then Install NuGet Pacakge `sqlite-net-wp8` from NuGet Package manager. check screenshot 2

[image]

then add Conditional Compilation symbol `USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE` in Project properties -> Build settings. check screenshot 3

[image]

Then Try to ReBuild the solutions and the errors will be gone..!

(I assumed that you've already copied those two files `SQLite.cs` and `SQLiteAsync.cs`)

Reference Links:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18204.how-to-use-sqlite-with-a-windows-phone-8-application.aspx

[Type or namespace 'Sqlite' could not be found in SQLite.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299779/type-or-namespace-sqlite-could-not-be-found-in-sqlite-cs)

Comment: I tried your steps but I get this warning and error : "Field 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection._preserveDuringLinkMagic' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value false  c:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SQLLite_Demo\SQLLite_Demo\SQLite.cs 241 15 SQLLite_Demo " and
 error : "Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.  0 0 
"

Comment: ignore the warning.. and for error, it clearly says that it seems like you haven't connected the windows phone to debug your app.
I suggest you first just try to ReBuild from the Build menu.